# neo4j relationships between nodes using a common property (id) without creating more nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been trying to match together two different nodes (process) and (process framework) that have the same id. I want to set a relationship between those (called:SAME). 
The query works but it creates 3 times the amount of processes that I wanted and I can´t figure out why:

```
MATCH (p:Process) 
MATCH (pcf:ProcessFramework) 
WHERE HAS (p.id) AND HAS (pcf.pcf_id) AND p.id=pcf.pcf_id
MERGE (p)<-[:same]-(pf)
return p,pcf
```

I also tried it with CREATE UNIQUE instead of MERGE but its the same result. I am not a developer so maybe I am doing a very obvious mistake but I really can´t see it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your query, you use `pf` where you should use `pcf` in the `MERGE`.

I'd also change it to this and make sure you have an index on `:ProcessFramework(pcf_id)`

```
MATCH (p:Process) 
MATCH (pcf:ProcessFramework) 
WHERE p.id=pcf.pcf_id
MERGE (p)<-[:same]-(pcf)
return p,pcf
```